# Can we scroll UIStackView

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uiscrollview, uistackview

I want to scroll ViewControllers vertically. in my app there are 4-5 ViewController is there which i want to scroll vertically. i have added UIStackView inside scrollview and give a try but it is not scrolling properly. i want to scroll like paging in scrollview but vertically.

i have also visited the link https://mecid.github.io/2019/02/27/building-complex-screens-with-child-viewcontrollers/
but i was not helpful.

Comment: Create a collectionview and add child viewcontrollers in each cell

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I agree you should use a collectionview here

Comment: https://medium.com/@hassanahmedkhan/scrolling-the-hell-out-of-stackview-33d239f9f38e

Answer (score 2):

You can't scroll the stackView directly, but you can contain it inside a scrollView and then it will scroll. If you look at the tutorial linked, that's exactly what they did:

```
view.addSubview(scrollView)
scrollView.addSubview(stackView)
```